# How to get current activity correctly?

Tags: java, android, kivy, pyjnius

I need to access current activity of my app. I checked [this official code](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/android.html#accessing-the-activity)

If i use this code below as documentation says:

```
PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
```

i can't access activity and it returns error. So after searching i found this:

```
PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
```

There is 2 function below. First one is opening webbrowser just like in documentation and **IT WORKS**:

```
from jnius import cast
from jnius import autoclass
PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri')
intent = Intent()
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.setData(Uri.parse('http://kivy.org'))
currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
currentActivity.startActivity(intent)
```

Now i need to recode this for my own script. I want to add new contact to Contacts. I got *'WRITE_CONTACTS'* permission for that. *in buildozer.spec:*

> android.permissions = WRITE_CONTACTS

But my own script returns me error. My function:

```
from jnius import autoclass,cast
PythonActivity=autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
JS=autoclass('java.lang.String')
intent=Intent()
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
intent.setType('ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE')
intent.putExtra('ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME',JS('Example Name'))
intent.putExtra('ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE',JS('7777777777'))
currentActivity=cast('android.app.Activity',PythonActivity.mActivity)
currentActivity.startActivity(intent)
```

Log:

> jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: No Activity found
> to handle Intent { typ=ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE (has
> extras) } android.content.ActivityNotFoundException

I don't know that Is this error eccours because of activity or my wrong type selection. I would be glad if anyone help me to handle this. Like this contents on media is very few. So i hope like this topics let people learn quickly just like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY, I found solution to access activities and getting Contacts datas.

Accessing correctly `PythonActivity`:

```
PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")
```

Accessing `Contacts` Java Class:

```
Contacts = autoclass("android.provider.ContactsContract$Contacts")
```

Accessing `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` Java Class (same):

```
Kinds = autoclass("android.provider.ContactsContract$CommonDataKinds$Phone")
```

Creating `getContentResolver()`:

```
cr = PythonActivity.mActivity.getContentResolver()
```

Now we need to create 2 query. In first, we are going to find **`ID`** and need to use it in second query to find equal **`NUMBER`**. Also need to check ***is contact has phone number?*** too. After that we can loop second query to find number:

```
name_number_dict= {}   # Name:Number  # Change as you wish..
while (que1.moveToNext()):  #Query 1 Loop
    if que1.getString(que1.getColumnIndex(Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)):  #If has number
        que2 = cr.query(Kinds.CONTENT_URI, None, Kinds.CONTACT_ID + " = " + que1.getString(que1.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_ID)), None, None)  #Query 2 Loop
        while (que2.moveToNext()):
            name_number_dict[que1.getString(que1.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))] = que2.getString(que2.getColumnIndex(Kinds.NUMBER)  # Get datas and put in dic.
```

If you need to check all ColumnNames of query, use `query1.getColumnNames()`  >> [Referance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor?authuser=2#getColumnNames())

I hope it helps you guys who need to use this in Python>Kivy applications..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Python syntax, but I can tell you what the problem is:

You are missing the `Intent` ACTION. You need to set the ACTION in the `Intent` to `ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION` (which has the string value `"android.intent.action.INSERT"`)

Also, it looks like you are sending Android **constant names** instead of the actual **string values** of these things, for example:

you do this:
intent.setType('ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE')

which sets the `type` in the `Intent` to the string value `"ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE"`, which you can see here:

> jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: No Activity found
> to handle Intent { typ=ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE (has
> extras) } android.content.ActivityNotFoundException

but the `type` needs to be set to the Android constant `ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE` which has the string value `"vnd.android.cursor.dir/raw_contact"`

As I said, I don't know Python syntax, but you probably need to do something like this:

```
intent=Intent()
intent.setAction(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION)
intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE)
```

or, if Python supports it, `Intent` has a constructor that takes an ACTION as a parameter, so this might also work:

```
intent=Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION)
intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE)
```

Let me know if any of this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Unfortinatly adding `ACTION_INSERT` didnt work for me.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the error message. It should be different now.